# Making random numbers (roll) that are different each time you run q

Tags: random, kdb

I'd like to use roll e.g.

```
1?6
```

to generate numbers that are different each time I restart q.

The fixed seed normally prevents this, e.g. every time I quit q, restart, and enter 1?6, I get 4.

I am imagining a complex solution but is there an easy, built-in solution you can think of?

Thanks so much.

Edit: I did try using deal (e.g. -1?6) which I thought according to the documentation should work, but it still gives the same number every startup. Any idea why?

Comment: If you use a fixed seed you'll get the very same sequence each time no matter what. Use a random seed instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misread your question initially - to make the random generator different each time you have to set a different seed number, see https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#s-random-seed

Something like

```
>q
KDB+ 4.0 2021.02.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2021 Kx Systems
w32/ 4()core 4095MB tlynch ctx-tlynch01 10.203.90.98 NONEXPIRE

q)system"S ",string"j"$.z.t
q)1?100
,73
q)\\

>q
KDB+ 4.0 2021.02.02 Copyright (C) 1993-2021 Kx Systems
w32/ 4()core 4095MB tlynch ctx-tlynch01 10.203.90.98 NONEXPIRE

q)system"S ",string"j"$.z.t
q)1?100
,52
```

The difference between roll and deal (position/negative) is that in deal the same value can't appear twice. No big reason to use `neg` rather than minus sign other than it makes it more obvious/explicit to the reader that it's a deal

Comment: Right, then it'd be not roll but deal which according to the documentation uses a seed based on the current time. I already tested deal though (perhaps should have mentioned) and it still gave the same number every startup. I wondered if your way of writing it changed anything (actually why DID you use neg rather than just a minus sign?) so I tested it and nope, still giving the same result every startup.

Comment: See edits above. If you're setting the seed to a non-deterministic number then you shouldn't be getting the same RNG results on every startup

Comment: Thanks so much!! I guess this counts as a complicated solution rather than the inbuilt solution I was thinking might exist. But it's perfect, thanks :)